# How to use a cell value as a row in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How can I use a cell value as a row in a formula?

For instance use the value of B1 and B2 to perform an average or sum of those rows?

```
=average([ValueofB1],[ValueofB2])?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1&":"&B2))
```

Assuming B1 = 1 and B2 = 3 this would be like typing `=AVERAGE(1:3)`

so it would average rows 1 to three.

To specify a different sheet then:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&B1&":"&B2))
```

If you want to specify the column as per your comments:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&C1&":A"&C2))
```

If in the active sheet you place this in B1, it will take the values of C1 and C2 of that sheet as the row values and look at column A on Sheet 1 in the rows specified.

Comment: Ok, that works for the current row and sheet but how could I specify it for a row and sheet that aren't the current row/sheet? Thanks for the help

For instance data is on sheet1 of row A1-A10, but I want the average function to show up on sheet 2 in B1 with the row numbers for the average in C1-C2 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The indirect function takes any string and converts it into a formula.

For example, you a 4 sheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4).  Let's assume that sheet 1 is your 'summary' sheet.  On the remainder sheets, you have a row of numbers in row 1 that you want to average.

In Sheet1, A1, A2, A3 you would have your sheet names and B1, B2 and B3 would have the rows that you want to average from each sheet.  Column C would have the averages in it.

This is what it would look like;

```
A1 'Sheet2
A2 'Sheet3
A3 'Sheet4

B1 3
B2 2
B3 6

C1 =average(indirect(A1&"!"&B1&":"&B1)
C2 =average(indirect(A2&"!"&B2&":"&B2)
C3 =average(indirect(A3&"!"&B3&":"&B2)
```

I hope that helps.

Greg